# Comment désigner deux noms féminin et masculin dans un pronom ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre

J'ai une phrase du style (Cette phrase ne veut rien dire mais c'est juste un exemple pour la syntaxe) :

> L'objectif était, pour chaque rocher et chaque pierre, de savoir qui le/la soulevait.

Pour homme/femme, l'utilisation de le/la est assez répandue. Mais pour des objets inanimés (rocher/pierre), cela semble plus maladroit...

Comment dois-je écrire cette phrase ?

Comment: « …de savoir qui **les** soulevait » ?

Comment: Mais est-ce que ça va avec "pour chaque" ?

Comment: Il y a un *et*, donc deux objets.

Comment: Ah oui, effectivement. Bon ben c'était rapide... :p Merci ! Je ferme ou je laisse ?

Comment: Comme tu veux, je peux convertir mon commentaire en réponse.

Comment: Ça me semble bien

Comment: Eh bien pour ma part je ne suis pas convaincu. Le "chaque" me semble en effet imposer le singulier. D'ailleurs il n'y a pas "deux objets" mais deux sortes d'objets, pour peut-être des centaines d'objets. Et puis tu peux aussi agrémenter la question en posant le problème avec "ou" à la place de "et" (si vraiment le "et" impose le pluriel, ce dont je doute).

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Oui, ça dépend de la façon dont on interprète la phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Si les rochers et les pierres sont distincts, le pluriel doit pouvoir s'utiliser mais la présence de « chaque » tempère cette opinion :

> L'objectif était, pour chaque rocher et chaque pierre, de savoir qui les soulevait.

Si les rochers et les pierres ne sont que des variantes des mêmes objets, [le singulier peut être utilisé](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4542). C'est aussi le cas si « ou » coordonne les deux déterminants au lieu de « et ». L'accord en genre se fait soit avec le plus proche, soit au masculin:

Plus proche (féminin) :

> L'objectif était, pour chaque rocher et chaque pierre, de savoir qui la soulevait.
>
> L'objectif était, pour chaque rocher ou chaque pierre, de savoir qui la soulevait.

« Neutre » (masculin) :

> L'objectif était, pour chaque rocher et chaque pierre, de savoir qui le soulevait.
>
> L'objectif était, pour chaque rocher ou chaque pierre, de savoir qui le soulevait.

Le masculin choque l'oreille et je l'éviterais ici. Pour contourner ce problème, il est recommandé d'inverser les termes coordonnés :

> L'objectif était, pour chaque pierre et/ou chaque rocher, de savoir qui le soulevait.

Cette dernière forme permet d'éviter toute controverse.

Comment: Il y a vraiment une règle qui dit qu'on peut choisir le plus proche ou le neutre (masculin) ? Super intéressant.

Comment: Oui, mais cette règle (ou cet usage) a été largement supplanté par la règle « le masculin l'emporte sur le féminin » depuis le  XVIIIe siècle. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_proximit%C3%A9

Answer (score 0):

J'ai une analyse peut-être un peu plus simple.
Pour l'exemple cité, « pour chaque rocher et chaque pierre », il y a un ET et pas un OU. Il s'agit donc d'un pluriel. La réponse est donc :

> L'objectif était, pour chaque rocher et chaque pierre, de savoir qui les soulevait.

Mais cela ne répond pas à la question de Nathan.
Prenons cet exemple :

> L'objectif était, pour chaque rocher ou chaque pierre, de savoir qui le soulevait.

J'utilise LE. Pourquoi : il y a un nom masculin et un nom féminin, c'est le masculin qui l'emporte.

Si on n'avait que des noms féminins, on aurait mis LA :

> L'objectif était, pour chaque planche ou chaque pierre, de savoir qui la soulevait.

Comment: Il ne faut pas écarter le singulier même avec *et*: [*Plus rarement, le verbe peut s’accorder au singulier lorsque les deux sujets coordonnés sont au singulier et qu’ils sont l’expression d’une seule et même idée, d’un tout, ou qu’ils désignent une seule réalité de plus d’une façon.*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4542)

Comment: @jilliagre: si on avait "pour tous les rochers et toutes les pierres, ..." il faudrait mettre "les", malgré cette règle. Ici ce n'est pas ça qui fait qu'on utilise le singulier mais l'emploi de "chaque".

Comment: @AnneAunyme La règle suppose que les sujets coordonnés sont au singulier. Avec un antécédent coordonnant deux pluriels, le pronom ne peut pas être au singulier. Je suis d'accord sur le fait que « chaque x et chaque y » impose, en tant que sujet, un verbe au singulier (chaque homme et chaque femme est libre, pas *sont *libres), mais je suis plus dubitatif dans le cas ou « chaque x et chaque y » est un antécédent. Je modifie ma réponse en conséquence.